# Two questions on Graham's conjecture

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, reference-request

Graham's conjecture states that $$\pi(G\times H)\le\pi(G)\pi(H)$$ where $\pi(G)$ denotes the pebbling number of a graph $G$.  I have the following two questions:

1. Are there examples of graphs $G$, $H$ with $\pi(G\times H)<\pi(G)\pi(H)$?
2. Let $\pi_L(G,v)$ denote the minimum number $n$ such that for any distribution with $n$ pebbles on $G$ it is possible to move a pebble on $v$.  Is anything known about the following, 'localized' version of the conjecture? $$\pi_L(G\times H,(v,w))\le\pi_L(G,v)\pi_L(H,w)$$ Is it plausible?  Are there counterexamples?